# How to convert svg to createjs.Graphics?

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I have some SVG. I want to convert to createjs.Graphics. Is there any tool to convert or any nodejs module to convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use Adobe Animate. Animate can import SVG and export a compressed graphics format for EaselJS.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Lanny, Thanks for the response.  When i converted the SVG using adobe cc it contains one MC which contain multiple shapes created for the SVG. I want to create a mask for one the Movieclip from the converted svg. I know that we cannot use movieclips for the masking. How can i convert multiple shapes to one? Or is there is another way

Comment: You should be able to break the shapes out of their symbols/groups. Just select them and CMD-B :)